# How do I retrieve files for a classic project from the XTRF API?

Tags: c#, xtrf

I have written a system which communicates with XTRF's Home Portal API. So far, I have managed to create projects, create tasks, add tasks and upload files.

However, when it comes to completed tasks in XTRF, I am unable to find a way to download the translated files through the Home Portal API.

Through a bit of investigation, I found that customers of a project can access the files through the Customer Portal API.

Using a combination of the two APIs, I can find a customer for each project, and then attempt to log in as that customer and download the files.

This doesn't seem like the best approach, and so far whenever I have tried to log in as a customer, I often get the response:

```
{"status" : 400, "errorMessage" : "Specified person is not allowed to login."}
```

This could be a licensing issue, however.
It would seem that either I need a customer which can be assigned to every project, which seems like getting around the problem rather than remedying it.

Or there is another way, which I have missed in the API documentation online.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled "Client Portal Access Allowed" in Client Settings. [Screeenshot for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7dDR.png)

Comment: This would solve the problem, but we require access to every clients files with an ever expanding client base. Ideally, we need a solution to access any clients files from one log in, but your solution may have to be what we go with.

Comment: Update: That setting is ticked, and I still get the same response. Not allowed to log in.